# MySQL Connector/C++ Vs the MySQL C API (MySQL client library)

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm developing an application using C++ and MySQL under Raspberry Pi B+.
I don't know if I should use **MySQL Connector/C++**  or just stay with the **MySQL C API (MySQL client library)**.

I have found the following benefits from their website :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-introduction.html

MySQL Connector/C++ offers the following benefits for C++ users compared to the MySQL C API (MySQL client library):

> Convenience of pure C++; no C function calls required
>
> Supports JDBC 4.0, an industry standard API
>
> Supports the object-oriented programming paradigm
>
> Reduces development time
>
> Licensed under the GPL with the FLOSS License Exception
>
> Available under a commercial license upon request

I want my Application to run faster since I have to save data in real time.
So I think I must use MySQL connector/C++, but I haven't found a download for **Raspberry Pi B+**, or maybe I have to download the source code and compile it myself.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you need can only be answered by YOU. Because YOU know what you want and need. You can download the connector by installing the package `libmysqlcppconn-dev` via `apt`. If that does not exist, use the sources and compile yourself...